# Seeing different animation behavior in Xcode Preview vs. Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

One of my Views is a pretty simple loading animation of three circles that expand/contract in size, but it's not animating in the same way in the Preview vs. the Simulator. In the Simulator (right), the circles move up and down in addition to expanding and contracting (undesired) whereas in the Preview (left) they only expand and contract (desired).

[image: Preview on the left, Simulator on the right]

I originally borrowed the code from [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/create-an-awesome-loading-state-using-swiftui-9815ff6abb80) and modified it slightly to support iOS 16:

```
struct LoadingView: View {
    let color: Color

    @State private var shouldAnimate = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(color)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .scaleEffect(shouldAnimate ? 1.0 : 0.5)
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever(), value: shouldAnimate)
            Circle()
                .fill(color)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .scaleEffect(shouldAnimate ? 1.0 : 0.5)
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever().delay(0.3), value: shouldAnimate)
            Circle()
                .fill(color)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .scaleEffect(shouldAnimate ? 1.0 : 0.5)
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever().delay(0.6), value: shouldAnimate)
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.shouldAnimate = true
        }
    }
}
```

Any input on why I might be seeing the difference in behavior?

Comment: If you are running macOS Monterey, then you are seeing "last year's SwiftUI" behaviors in the previews.  In the iOS 16 simulators, you are seeing the new SwiftUI behaviors.  This seems to be an annual occurrence when we're switching to a new version of SwiftUI.  You should trust the emulators and not previews for an accurate representation of the animations.

Comment: Could you add the code to the question for the View that uses LoadingView so that we can reproduce your animation problem.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the preview is showing the current SwiftUI behavior after all -- the issue appears to have been running the animation inside a NavigationView (when I update the preview to use a NavigationView, it matches what I see in the Simulator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a known potential issue when running an animation inside a `NavigationView`: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682779

Updated code that appears to function as expected:

```
struct LoadingView: View {
    let color: Color

    @State private var shouldAnimateFirst = false
    @State private var shouldAnimateSecond = false
    @State private var shouldAnimateThird = false
    
    var body: some View {
        let firstAnimation = Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever()
        let secondAnimation = Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever().delay(0.3)
        let thirdAnimation = Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever().delay(0.6)
    
        HStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(color)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .scaleEffect(shouldAnimateFirst ? 1.0 : 0.5)
        
            Circle()
                .fill(color)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .scaleEffect(shouldAnimateSecond ? 1.0 : 0.5)
        
            Circle()
                .fill(color)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .scaleEffect(shouldAnimateThird ? 1.0 : 0.5)
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                withAnimation(firstAnimation) {
                    shouldAnimateFirst = true
                }
            
                withAnimation(secondAnimation) {
                    shouldAnimateSecond = true
                }
            
                withAnimation(thirdAnimation) {
                    shouldAnimateThird = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```